# Suggestions for editing Docker-based Web app?

Tags: javascript, performance, docker, web-applications

I would like make some changes to the code of https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf and its relevent component (residing in an own repository) https://github.com/overleaf/web and see how it works out. However, I have not figured out an efficient and fast way to do this. My best guess so far was to fork the web repo, make changes locally and push them. Then I forked the overleaf/overleaf repo, edited the services.js file to use my remote web git and ran

```
docker build -f Dockerfile-base -t sharelatex/sharelatex-base .
docker build -f Dockerfile -t sharelatex/sharelatex .
docker-compose up
```

to build the Docker image and use docker-compose to get everything running. However this whole process takes me around 10 minutes for some tiny changes like the insertion of a few characters. Does somebody have a suggestion how to improve that?

Comment: This question in its current form is only answerable by people who set up or work with that specific project's Docker workflow; I'd recommend posting it on whatever issues board they offer.

Comment: Generally an app should have a "watch" mode for development, which allows you to run a local development server of some sort which will recompile files on the fly and/or reload the web server on any file changes. Building a Docker image is usually for making a more optimised production build. That obviously depends on the specific project in question…